# Separate image object into N sections of equal pixels (Approach)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, opencv, image-processing, theory

Sorry in advance, this is more of an algorithmic problem rather than a coding problem, but I wasn't sure where to put it. For simplicity sake, say you have a binary image (white background, solid black object in foreground)

Example:
[sample input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OeuO.png)

I want to divide this object (meaning only the black pixels) into N sections, all with the same number of pixels (so each section should contain (1/N)*(total # of black pixels)).

With the current algorithm that I'm using, I (1) find the total number of black pixels and (2) divide by N. Then I (3) scan the image row by row marking all black pixels. The result looks something like this:

[current output sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgtil.png)

The problem with this is the last (yellow) section, which isn't continuous. I want to divide the image in a way that makes more sense, like this:

[ideal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPLpm.png)

Basically, I'd like the boundary between the sections to be as short as possible.

I've been stumped on this for a while, but my old code just isn't cutting it anymore. I only need an approach to identifying the sections, I'll ultimately be outputting each section as individual images, as well as a grayscale copy of the input image where every pixel's value corresponds to its section number (these things I don't need help with). Any ideas?

Comment: So section number will be 6 ? Or changable?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk changeable

Answer (score 1):

> I only need an approach to identifying the sections

According to this, I tried couple of approaches, these may help for guidelines:

- Find contour of the image
- Find the [moments](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html) of contour and detect mass center.
- For outer corners, you can simply use [convex hull](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1d/tutorial_hull.html)
- Find the closest contour points(which are will be inner corners) to mass center
- Then you can seperate it to desired regions by using these important points

Here is the result and code:

[image]

```
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

vector<Point>innerCorners;
bool isClose(Point test);
int main()
{
    Mat src_gray;
    int thresh = 100;
    Mat src = imread("image/dir/star.png");
    cvtColor( src, src_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
    namedWindow( "Source",WINDOW_NORMAL );

    Mat canny_output;
    Canny( src_gray, canny_output, thresh, thresh*2 );
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    findContours( canny_output, contours, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    vector<vector<Point> >hull( contours.size() );

    vector<Moments> mu(contours.size() );
    for( int i = 0; i <(int)contours.size(); i++ )
    { mu[i] = moments( contours[i], false ); }

    for( size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
     {
         if(contours[i].size()>20)
             convexHull( contours[i], hull[i] );
     }

    vector<Point2f> mc( contours.size() );
    for( int i = 0; i <(int)contours.size(); i++ )
    { mc[i] = Point2f( mu[i].m10/mu[i].m00 , mu[i].m01/mu[i].m00 ); }

    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( canny_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );
    int onlyOne = 1;
    for( size_t i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
    {
        if(contours[i].size()>20 && onlyOne)
        {
            circle( src, mc[i], 4, Scalar(0,255,255), -1, 8, 0 );
            Scalar color = Scalar(255,0,0);
            drawContours( drawing, contours, (int)i, color );
            drawContours( src, hull, (int)i, color,5 );

            Point centerMass = mc[i];
            for(int a=0; a<(int)contours[i].size();a++)
            {
                if(cv::norm(cv::Mat(contours[i][a]),Mat(centerMass))<200 && isClose(contours[i][a]))
                {
                    circle(src,contours[i][a],5,Scalar(0,0,255),10);
                    innerCorners.push_back(contours[i][a]);
                    line(src,contours[i][a],centerMass,Scalar(0,255,255),5);
                }
            }

            onlyOne = 0;
        }
    }
    namedWindow( "Hull demo",WINDOW_NORMAL );
    imshow( "Hull demo", drawing );
    imshow("Source", src );


    waitKey();
    return 0;
}

bool isClose(Point test){
    if(innerCorners.size()==0)
        return 1;

    for(Point a:innerCorners)
        if((cv::norm(cv::Mat(a),cv::Mat(test)))<70)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I like the contour and mass center aspects. However, I'm not sure I understand how the convex hull will be reliable for any other input that is not a star. For example, if I put a rectangle in, the sections will not come out with equal pixels. Is there another way around this?

Comment: I couldnt think variantly. So difficult to find approaches for any shape.